# Angular directive with dynamic templateUrl and Transclude

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here's the issue. I need to pass a directive2 into directive1. Directive1 has a dynamic templateUrl.  A template has a section that would host transcluded code (another directive). This does not work unless I surround element.find (below) with a $timeout.  Once the page is rendered, the directive will be embedded into the template.  But I can't get it to work without the timeout.

```
<directive1>
  <directive2></directive>
</directive1>
```

Directive1

```
app.directive("directive1", function() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<ng-include src="getTemplateUrl()" />',
        scope: {
            id: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller, transclude) {
            scope.getTemplateUrl = function () {
                return "template" + scope.id + ".html";
            };

            element.find(".placeholderForDirective2").append(transclude());

        }
    }
})
```

Template1:

```
<div>
    <div class="placeholderForDirective2"></div>
    <div>blah blah blah</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely expected: `ng-include` is asynchronous, while the code in the link function is synchronous. The `element.find()` will run most certainly *before* Angular has had the time to fetch the `"template" + scope.id + ".html"`.

You can listen to `ng-include`'s `'$includeContentLoaded'` event and then call `element.find()`:

```
scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function() {
    element.find(".placeholderForDirective2").append(transclude());
});
```

Comment: You beat me by six seconds :)

Answer (score 2):

[ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) provides a couple of options to be notified when the template is loaded.

You can use the `onload` attribute to evaluate an expression when the template is loaded:

`<ng-include src="getTemplateUrl()" onload="myFunction()" />`

It also emits events that you can listen for, specifically the `$includeContentLoaded` event.

`scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', myFunction);`

Comment: This is a much much better approach than rummaging around in the DOM with `element.find().`

Comment: That was 6 seconds indeed :D